# How much logging is done in Data Centers?

Tags: datacenter

How much data is usually logged in data centers?  Now I mean by the actual facilitator, not the individual clients renting space.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the data center and their policies. There is no standard.

Comment: Well of course, but whats a standard amount, an average.

Comment: Since there doesn't exist a list of datacenters and their policies, this question doesn't have an answer. I guess it is a save bet to say that the minimum amount of logging any DC does is data transfer in and out, per client. Everything else is speculation.

Comment: Like SvenW said...it's speculation. There is no "standard". We could make assumations, but that's still pure speculation. And even if you asked them, you might get a half-truth or partial answer. Or an answer they think is honest but someone else knows isn't being followed (yeah, we monitor bandwidth per server...when really it's an aggregate at the router...)

There's no standard.

Answer (score 2):

Carrier neutral datacenters will typically not log anything but access controls and power usage.

People you get 'internet' from may log a bit more, from a technical perspective: your throughput graphs (Mbit/s and packets/s). If an incident occurs they may look into it a bit more, producing logs in the process. Example: your site is being dossed or is participating in a dos attack. Allmost everyone will log dynamic IP's to an accout.
Legally there may be requirements in terms of saving log information for law enforcement. That typiscally consists of tcp from/to and timestamp.